# How to get response in ajax call of Json type in php?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I cant get data in success of ajax call.In success data remains blank. How can i get data in response.....................................................................................................................................................................................................

**reports.blade.php**

```
    $.ajax({
              type : "POST",
              url : '{{ url('filter_reports') }}',
              dataType: 'json',
              data : {
                'hours_from' : hours_from,
                'hours_to' : hours_to,
                'ddl_promotion' : ddl_promotion,
                'ddl_shops' : ddl_shops,
                'ddl_age_from' : ddl_age_from,
                'ddl_age_to' : ddl_age_to,
                'from_date' : from_date,
                'to_date' : to_date,
                'ddl_mall_center' : ddl_mall_center,
                'ddl_postal_code' : ddl_postal_code,
                'ddl_gender' : ddl_gender,
                'ddl_report_type' : ddl_report_type,
                'ddl_report_graph' : ddl_report_graph,
                '_token' : '{{ csrf_token() }}'
              },
              success : function(data)
              {
                if((ddl_report_type == 1 || ddl_report_type == 3 || ddl_report_type == 6 || ddl_report_type == 7) && ddl_report_graph == 1)
                {
                  $('#myChart').replaceWith('<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>');
                  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');    
                  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                      labels: **data.x,**
                      datasets: [{
                        label: 'Participants',
                        data: **data.y,**
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                        borderWidth: 2
                      }]
                    },
                    options: {
                      title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Participants'
                      },
                      scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                          gridLines: {
                            display: false
                          }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{ 
                          gridLines: {
                            display: false
                          },                    
                          ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true,
                            min:**data.min,**
                            max:**data.max**
                          }                
                        }]
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
```

**ReportsController.php**

```
if($report_graph == 1 || $report_graph == 2 || $report_graph == 3)
          {
            $get_data = DB::select("SELECT p.p_id,p.name,c.age FROM tbl_capture_img AS cap JOIN tbl_customers AS c ON c.c_id = cap.c_id JOIN tbl_promotions AS p ON p.p_id = cap.p_id WHERE cap.p_id = '{$promotion}'");
            $agerange = array('18-30','31-40','41-50','51-60','61-70','71-80','81-90','91-100');
            $final_age_range = '['.implode(',',$agerange).']';
            $agecount = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
            foreach($get_data as $data)
            {
              if($data->age >=18 && $data->age <= 30)
              {
                $agecount[0] += 1;
              }
              else if($data->age >=31 && $data->age <= 40)
              {
                $agecount[1] += 1;
              }
              else if($data->age >=41 && $data->age <= 50)
              {
                $agecount[2] += 1;
              }
              else if($data->age >=51 && $data->age <= 60)
              {
                $agecount[3] += 1;
              }
              else if($data->age >=61 && $data->age <= 70)
              {
                $agecount[4] += 1;
              }
              else if($data->age >=71 && $data->age <= 80)
              {
                $agecount[5] += 1;
              }
              else if($data->age >=81 && $data->age <= 90)
              {
                $agecount[6] += 1;
              }
              else if($data->age >=91 && $data->age <= 100)
              {
                $agecount[7] += 1;
              }
            }
            $final_age_count = '['.implode(',',$agecount).']';
            $final['x'] = $final_age_range;
            $final['y'] = $final_age_count;

            $final['min'] = 0;
            $final['max'] = max($agecount) + 5;
            echo json_encode($final);
          }
```

**Output**

```
{"x":"[18-30,31-40,41-50,51-60,61-70,71-80,81-90,91-100]","y":"[4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]","min":0,"max":9}
```

But i cant get array in **data.x,data.y,data.min,data.max** so graph remains blank. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to troubleshoot codes like this:

First check, Ajax response is correct(and even json) with console.log():

```
success : function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
```

If it has values that you expected, ensure which you if block run with and alert() or similar console.log().

```
if((ddl_report_type == 1 || ddl_report_type == 3 || ddl_report_type == 6 || ddl_report_type == 7) && ddl_report_graph == 1)
{
     alert("hi"); or console.log("hi");
```

if everything was fine you does not have access to  data in your  labels: **data.x,** and you need do define a global variable and after access with that:

```
success : function(data)
{
    var gData = data;
```

and use:

```
labels: **gData.x,**
```

if each step rejected you need to fix that, for example if data does not had any value there is an issue in your Laravel PHP Controller or communication structure.

Also it is possible to get data as string and you need to pare it as json in your JavaScript(var parsedObjext = JSON.parse(data);).

Answer (score 0):

In your reports.blade.php file: add the following line inside the success of ajax as below:

```
....
success : function(data)
          {
           data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

 /*Add this above line and you can then access data.x and data.y*/


            if((ddl_report_type == 1 || ddl_report_type == 3 || ddl_report_type == 6 || ddl_report_type == 7) && ddl_report_graph == 1)
            {
```